# I cannot find the locator for this dropdown list of below HTML code and picture

Tags: selenium, xpath

[image]

I cannot find out the locator for "Scotiabank American Express Card".

Please see the code below:

```
<li>
    <a id="inputBox" class="menulink menuhover">Scotia Mortgage</a>
    <ul id="listOptions" style="overflow:visible; display:block; height:148px; z-index:414; visibility:visible; opacity:1;">
        <li>
        <li>
            <a class="sub ">Credit Card</a>
            <ul style="overflow:hidden; display:block; height:0px; z-index:415; opacity:0.0153846;">
                <li class="topline">
                    <a class="sub">American Express</a>
                    <ul style="overflow:hidden; display:block; height:0px; z-index:401; opacity:0.0153846;">
                        <li class="topline">
                            <a onclick="changeValue(this, 'AmExRegular')">Scotiabank American Express Card</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a onclick="changeValue(this, 'AmExGold')">Scotiabank Gold American Express Card</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="bottomline">
                            <a onclick="changeValue(this, 'AmExPlatinum')">Scotiabank Platinum Amex Card</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                <li class="bottomline">
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
        <li>
        <li>
        <li>
        <li class="bottomline">
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you please share your code ?

Answer (score 0):

search by text

```
//a[text()='Scotiabank American Express Card']
```

Comment: it is also not working... I have tried using 
    .//*[@id='listOptions']/li[2]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a 
also... but no progress....